# Why state array is not populated when component is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have created a component that sorts and filters an HTML table. The functionality is correct but I have a problem where my table renders **"No asset records found."** but when I click on one of the headers it displays the contents of the data array in state. I am truly stuck and confused on this strange behaviour. I think the problem might be with the `filterAssets` function because if I change from this:

```
let filterAssets = this.state.data.filter(a => {
  return a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
})
```

to this:

```
let filterAssets = this.props.assetManagement.filter(a => {
  return a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
})
```

Here is the code below if it helps

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { getAssetManagement } from '../../actions/asset-management'

class AssetManagement extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    assetManagement: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getAssetManagement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAssetManagement()
  }

  state = {
    name: '',
    search: '',
    data: []
  }

  sortBy = this.sortBy.bind(this)
  compareBy = this.compareBy.bind(this)

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onChange = e =>
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })

  updateSearch = e =>
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value.substr(0, 20)
    })

  compareBy(key) {
    return (a, b) => {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1
      return 0
    }
  }

  sortBy(key) {
    let arrayCopy = [...this.props.assetManagement]
    this.state.data.sort(this.compareBy(key))
    this.setState({ data: arrayCopy })
  }

  render() {
    let filterAssets = this.state.data.filter(a => {
      return a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
    })

    return (
      <Fragment>
        {/* Search input */}
        <div class="input-group mb-1">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text btn-secondary">
              <i class="fas fa-search" />
            </span>
          </div>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search Asset"
            onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.search}
          />
        </div>

        {/* Asset management table */}
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table table-bordered text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('id')}>ID</th>
                <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('name')}>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {filterAssets != 0 ? (
                filterAssets.map(a => (
                  <tr key={a.id}>
                    <td>{a.id}</td>
                    <td>{a.name}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <tr>
                  <td colSpan={6}>No asset records found.</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  assetManagement: state.assetManagement.assetManagement
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getAssetManagement }
)(AssetManagement)
```

Comment: assetManagement is already an array so I wonder whether your use of the spread operator in the constructor is causing the issue?

Comment: @Marcus I have already removed it and doesn't do anything

Comment: I am going to edit the code so that the spread is not in there and keep as empty array @randomSoul

Answer (score 0):

Change `filterAssets != 0` to `filterAssets.length > 0`

One first render:

```
let filterAssets = this.state.data.filter(a => {
  return a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
})
```

Your `this.state.data` is empty, only `this.props.assetManagement` available if you handle redux properly so no wonder it you cannot get anything from filtering.

Btw: `filterAssets != 0` is absolutely wrong, so go ahead and change this line first.

Comment: What should the `filterAssets` be? change it to `this.props.assetManagement`

Comment: The problem with what you have said is that now I can't sort the data by their headings. They don't change but the data shows now

Comment: Okay, I got you on this. You can use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) or something else to change `this.state.data` when receiving data from redux

Comment: I might just remove it altogether. Very confusing to me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you use the alternative syntax for a React Component without using a constructor you no longer have access to props. So if you go back to using a standard constructor the problem disappears, e.g.:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      search: "",
      data: this.props.assetManagement
    };

    this.sortBy = this.sortBy.bind(this);
    this.compareBy = this.compareBy.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the problem

Answer (score 0):

The real problem you have here is that you have two source of data: `state.data` and `props.assetManagement` - you retrieve from redux and get newest data from `props.assetManagement`, but when you need to trigger sorting, you make a copy to `state.data`. Then problem arises since you don't copy from `props.assetManagement` to `state.data` until you trigger `sortBy` function.

A solution for that is to get rid of `state.data` and store the sorting key in state. You can update, reset that key value, and sorting logic should be apply to `props.assetManagement` only:

```
class AssetManagement extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    assetManagement: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getAssetManagement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAssetManagement()
  }

  state = {
    name: '',
    search: '',
    sortingKey: ''
  }

  sortBy = this.sortBy.bind(this)
  compareBy = this.compareBy.bind(this)

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onChange = e =>
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })

  updateSearch = e =>
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value.substr(0, 20)
    })

  compareBy(key) {
    return (a, b) => {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1
      return 0
    }
  }

  sortBy(key) {
    if (key !== this.state.sortingKey) {
      this.setState({ sortingKey: key });
    }
  }

  render() {
    let sortAssets = !!this.state.sortingKey ?
      this.props.assetManagement.sort(this.compareBy(this.state.sortingKey)) :
      this.props.assetManagement;
    let filterAssets = sortAssets.filter(a => {
      return a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
    });
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {/* Search input */}
        <div class="input-group mb-1">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text btn-secondary">
              <i class="fas fa-search" />
            </span>
          </div>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search Asset"
            onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.search}
          />
        </div>

        {/* Asset management table */}
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table table-bordered text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('id')}>ID</th>
                <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('name')}>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {filterAssets != 0 ? (
                filterAssets.map(a => (
                  <tr key={a.id}>
                    <td>{a.id}</td>
                    <td>{a.name}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <tr>
                  <td colSpan={6}>No asset records found.</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/n91pq7073l

Comment: Thank you. I have looked through the code and try to understand what you did. Great!

Comment: @User123 My bad, I removed the filter logic. Added it back.

Comment: Yeah I did and it works initially but not when I have clicked and sorted the header's column

Comment: @User123 you mean sorting and searching don't work together? How about sorting only or searching only? It feels quite weird...

Comment: Do you know how I can do both?

Comment: @User123 I have created a codesandbox to illustrate my code. Please check editted answer. I suspect that you search with uppercase text, like "Bob" instead of "bob". Since your logic uses `a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf` to filter, it will reject uppercase search. Otherwise my solution works as intended.